# Spearman correlation between Ordinal dependent variable and other variables in a dataset error

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, ordinal-data

I try to run this part of my code

```
# Calculate spearman correlation test between the ordinal dependent variable and other variables
spearman_corr <- map_dbl(other_vars, function(x) cor(dataset[[x]], dataset[[ordinal_dep_var]], method = "spearman"))
```

and got this error,

```
Error in `vectbl_as_col_location2()`:
```

! Can't extract column with `ordinal_dep_var`.
✖ Subscript `ordinal_dep_var` must be size 1, not 1000.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. The Dependent variable is a column with levels (Low, Medium, High)

The purpose is to later run this to get the significant ones

```r
# Select significant variables based on the spearman correlation test
significant_vars <- other_vars[abs(spearman_corr) > 0.5]
```

then use that and create an ordinal logistics regression to predict the level

here's a link to my dataset if needed [cancer dataset](https://stdneuedutr-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/20195684_std_neu_edu_tr/EVETrArAblhPnSzLaqCqjQEBExKOELT8Ql0PYNfdCNxJdw?rtime=nSeqQSLp2kg)

and here's my full code snippet

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You likely need `dataset[["ordinal_dep_var"]]` (note the quotes) instead.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Yeah that didn't work instead gave this error "Error in cor(dataset[[x]], dataset[["ordinal_dep_var"]], method = "spearman") : 
supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```r
dataset <- rio::import("~/Downloads/cancer patient data sets (1) (1).xlsx")
dataset$ordinal_dep_var <- factor(dataset$Level, levels=c("Low", "Medium", "High"))
other_vars <- setdiff(colnames(dataset), c("ordinal_dep_var", "Level", "Patient Id"))
spearman_corr <- purrr::map_dbl(other_vars, function(x) cor(dataset[[x]], as.numeric(dataset[["ordinal_dep_var"]]), method = "spearman"))
spearman_corr
#>  [1]  0.07939082 -0.16486688  0.62146621  0.68179201  0.70278907  0.66097744
#>  [7]  0.67560519  0.61380590  0.69247738  0.81536376  0.48428460  0.68314269
#> [13]  0.65498263  0.76631837  0.63116882  0.35430186  0.48394304  0.20381774
#> [19]  0.23153439  0.31123246  0.45911148  0.35320136  0.28226940
```

Note, that you need to remove the `Patient Id` and `Level` variables (as they are not numeric) and turn the `ordinal_dep_var` into numeric.  You actually don't need `map_dbl`, you can do it all with `cor()`:

```r
spearman_corr <- cor(dataset[,other_vars], as.numeric(dataset$ordinal_dep_var), method="spearman")
spearman_corr
#>                                 [,1]
#> Age                       0.07939082
#> Gender                   -0.16486688
#> Air Pollution             0.62146621
#> Alcohol use               0.68179201
#> Dust Allergy              0.70278907
#> OccuPational Hazards      0.66097744
#> Genetic Risk              0.67560519
#> chronic Lung Disease      0.61380590
#> Balanced Diet             0.69247738
#> Obesity                   0.81536376
#> Smoking                   0.48428460
#> Passive Smoker            0.68314269
#> Chest Pain                0.65498263
#> Coughing of Blood         0.76631837
#> Fatigue                   0.63116882
#> Weight Loss               0.35430186
#> Shortness of Breath       0.48394304
#> Wheezing                  0.20381774
#> Swallowing Difficulty     0.23153439
#> Clubbing of Finger Nails  0.31123246
#> Frequent Cold             0.45911148
#> Dry Cough                 0.35320136
#> Snoring                   0.28226940
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks alot.